# Using odo to migrate data to SQL

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, blaze

I have a large 3 GB CSV file, and I'd like to use Blaze to investigate the data, select down to the data I'm interesting in analyzing, with the eventual goal to migrate that data into a suitable computational backend such as SQlite, PostgresSQL etc. I can get that data into Blaze and work on it fine, but this is the part I'm having trouble with:

```
db = odo(bdata, 'sqlite:///report.db::report')`
```

I'm not sure how to properly create a db file to open with sqlite.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can go directly from CSV to sqlite using the directions listed here.
http://odo.pydata.org/en/latest/perf.html?highlight=sqlite#csv-sqlite3-57m-31s
I think you are missing the column names as warned about here: http://odo.pydata.org/en/latest/sql.html?highlight=sqlite

```
dshape = discover(resource('report_2015.csv'))
t = odo('report_2015.csv', 'sqlite:///report.db::report', dshape=dshape)
```