# Read csv into database SQLite3 ODO Python

Tags: python, csv, sqlite, odo

I am trying to read in a csv into a new table in a new databased using ODO, SQLite3 and Python.

I am following these guides:

https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/odo/latest/odo.pdf
http://odo.pydata.org/en/latest/perf.html?highlight=sqlite#csv-sqlite3-57m-31s

I am trying the following:

```
import sqlite3
import csv
from odo import odo

file_path = 'my_path/'
# In this case 'my_path/' is a substitute for my real path

db_name = 'data.sqlite'

conn = sqlite3.connect(file_path + db_name)
```

This creates a new sqlite file `data.sqlite` within `file_path`. I can see it there in the folder.

When I then try to read my csv into this database I get the following error:

```
csv_path = 'my_path/data.csv'
odo(csv_path, file_path + db_name)
conn.close()

NotImplementedError: Unable to parse uri to data resource: # lists my path
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No thanks to the ODO documentation, this succesfully created a new table in a new database and read in the csv file to that database:

```
import sqlite3
import csv
from odo import odo

# [1]

#  Specify file path
file_path = 'my_path/'
# In this case 'my_path/' is a substitute for my real path

# Specify csv file path and name
csv_path = file_path + 'data.csv'

# Specify database name
db_name = 'data.sqlite'

# Connect to new database
conn = sqlite3.connect(file_path + db_name)

# [2]

# Use Odo to detect the shape and datatype of your csv:
data_shape = discover(resource(csv_path))

# Ready in csv to new table called 'data' within database 'data.sqlite'
odo(pd.read_csv(csv_path), 'sqlite:///' + file_path + 'data.sqlite::data', dshape=data_shape)

# Close database
conn.close()
```

Sources used in [1]:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html
[python odo sql AssertionError: datashape must be Record type, got 0 * {...}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44598799/python-odo-sql-assertionerror-datashape-must-be-record-type-got-0)

Sources used in [2]:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41584832/2254228
http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_sqlite_in_python_tutorial.html#creating-a-new-sqlite-database
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33316230/2254228
[what is difference between .sqlite and .db file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847067/what-is-difference-between-sqlite-and-db-file)

The ODO documentation is here (good luck...) https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/odo/latest/odo.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I found the document in the document website and in github are different. Please use github version as reference.

The

> NotImplementedError: Unable to parse uri to data resource

error is mentioned in this [section](https://github.com/blaze/odo/blob/master/docs/source/overview.rst#enabling-conversions).

You could solve by using

`pip install odo[sqlite]` or
`pip install odo[sqlalchemy]`

Then you may encounter another error if you use windows and odo 0.5.0:

> AttributeError: 'DiGraph object has no attribute 'edge'

Install networkx 1.11 instead of networkx 2.0 could solve this error.
([reference](https://github.com/blaze/odo/issues/579))

```
pip uninstall networkx
pip install networkx==1.11
```

I hope this will help